# Bitcoin CreateMultiSig in PHP always returning FALSE

Tags: multi-signature

I am using bitcoind 0.8.5 with JSON to try and implement multisignature addresses locally on my server. 
But when I try and create one from my code, it keeps returning FALSE.

`$create_multisig = $bitcoin->createmultisig (2, '[ "02e280809f7a7e0fabb7404d68ef89b66e9cf63ecfffd37ef2c78d06c51d2247f6", "02f22be70ae35432c82e7b05846eeab1fec5b09ebe523bb98d6d6bbf1ff29d96c3"]');`

var_dump($create_multisig);

I have tried variations of the quotes, I tried putting the public keys into variables, etc.. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? It won't create the multisignature address.

EDIT:

`$pubkey_str = "";`

$pubkey_str .= "\"02e280809f7a7e0fabb7404d68ef89b66e9cf63ecfffd37ef2c78d06c51d2247f6\",";

$pubkey_str .= "\"02f22be70ae35432c82e7b05846eeab1fec5b09ebe523bb98d6d6bbf1ff29d96c3\",";

$pubkey_str = substr($pubkey_str, 0, (strlen($pubkey_str)-1));

$pubkey_input = "'[$pubkey_str]'";

var_dump($pubkey_input);

$create_multisig = $bitcoin->addmultisigaddress (2, $pubkey_input);

var_dump($create_multisig);

And the resulting output

`string(141) "'["02e280809f7a7e0fabb7404d68ef89b66e9cf63ecfffd37ef2c78d06c51d2247f6","02f22be70ae35432c82e7b05846eeab1fec5b09ebe523bb98d6d6bbf1ff29d96c3"]'"`

bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

I lost my guest session but I figured out the problem.

jsonRPCClient was not providing me any useful information as an output so serching Stack Exchange I was able to find somebody who changed the JSON library to output a useful error code.

```
    Add *'ignore_errors' => true* to the $opts array
    Change the error line that throws Request error to read throw new Exception('Request error: '.$response['error']['code'].' - '.$response['error']['message']);.
```

Then the output said that I was inputting a string and I should be inputting an array. So all I had to do, was put all the public keys into an array and plug it into the createmultisig function.

```
$pubkey_str = array();

$pubkey_str[] = "02e280809f7a7e0fabb7404d68ef89b66e9cf63ecfffd37ef2c78d06c51d2247f6";

$pubkey_str[] = "02f22be70ae35432c82e7b05846eeab1fec5b09ebe523bb98d6d6bbf1ff29d96c3";


$create_multisig = $bitcoin->createmultisig (2,$pubkey_str);
var_dump($create_multisig);
```

and this was the output

```
array(2) { ["address"]=> string(35) "2MtXTzX7pASPKr8VKmkyWKRNFt2o1oFxi9K" ["redeemScript"]=> string(142) "522102e280809f7a7e0fabb7404d68ef89b66e9cf63ecfffd37ef2c78d06c51d2247f62102f22be70ae35432c82e7b05846eeab1fec5b09ebe523bb98d6d6bbf1ff29d96c352ae"
```

Which is exactly what I expected. So maybe it was a stupid mistake on my behalf, but hopefully other people can benefit from it.